# onPrimary deprecation -> migration fail on Flutter 3.3.0

Tags: flutter

In Flutter 3.3.0 primary should never used because of deprecation... by right clicking on primary I get a migration hint to change primary -> foregroundColor...

But the onPrimary property is also deprecated. The migration guide says: change onPrimary to foregroundColor **(there is no onForegroundColor)**... but there is the problem. onPrimary should be in high contrast to primary.

What is to do here?

Code Example:

```
ElevatedButtonThemeData getElevatedButtonTheme(ColorScheme colorScheme, TextTheme textTheme) => ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32)),
        elevation: 1,
        primary: colorScheme.secondary,
        onPrimary: colorScheme.onSecondary,
        textStyle: textTheme.button,
      ),
    );
```

update:
by clicking in the flutter code I found a comment "..use disabledForegroundColor..."

Comment: Instead of editing your question that you found the solution it's better to write your solution as an answer. [It's allowed and even encouraged to answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems the comment was wrong...
primary is backgroundColor and
onPrimary is foreground

But **only** for `ElevatedButtonThemeData`

```
ElevatedButtonThemeData getElevatedButtonTheme(ColorScheme colorScheme, TextTheme textTheme) => ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32)),
        elevation: 1,
        backgroundColor: colorScheme.secondary,
        foregroundColor: colorScheme.onSecondary,
        textStyle: textTheme.button,
      ),
    );
```